# Type errors when creating incremental date column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have data [read_data] as :

```
month 
0
1
2
```

I have a code to create column date as:

```
start = 201907  #This is YYYYMM
start_dt = pd.to_datetime(start, format='%Y%m')
read_data['date'] = read_data['month'].apply(lambda x: pd.DateOffset(months=x-1)).add(start_dt)
```

Basically trying to crate an incremental date column starting with date-1 at month 0

gives me error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'numpy.ndarray' and 'Timestamp'
```

Trying to get the result data as:

```
month  date
0      1/6/2019
1      1/7/2019
2      1/8/2019
```

Any ideas what the problem could be.

Comment: use a string instead of an integer; `start = "201907"`, otherwise, pd.to_datetime will assume the input represents nanoseconds since the epoch by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move it inside

```
df['date'] = df['month'].apply(lambda x: pd.DateOffset(months=x-1)+start_dt)
df
Out[69]: 
   month       date
0      0 2019-06-01
1      1 2019-07-01
2      2 2019-08-01
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
In [349]: df['date'] = df.month.apply(lambda x: start_dt.date() + pd.DateOffset(months=x-1))

In [350]: df
Out[350]: 
   month       date
0      0 2019-06-01
1      1 2019-07-01
2      2 2019-08-01
```